# How to Load Array values to Template Variable in Meteor JS?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How to Load Array values to Template Variable in Meteor?. Please see the below code and suggest me what to do?

HTML Code :

```
 <template name="header">
 <div class="header">
    {{#each alphabets}}
       <div class="alphabets">{{this}}</div>
    {{/each}}
 </div>
</template>
```

JS Code :

```
 //the below array values are load dynamically above template
 var Alphas = ['ALL',
              'A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E', 'F',
              'G', 'H', 'I', 'J','K', 'L',
              'M', 'N', 'O', 'P','Q', 'R',
              'S', 'T', 'U', 'V','W', 'X',
              'Y', 'Z'
              ]

        Template.header.alphabets = function (i)
         {
           return Alphas[i];
         };
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Template html:

```
<template name="header">
  <div class="header">
    {{#each alphabets}}
      <div class="alphabets">{{this}}</div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

Template js:

```
var Alphas = ['ALL',
              'A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E', 'F',
              'G', 'H', 'I', 'J','K', 'L',
              'M', 'N', 'O', 'P','Q', 'R',
              'S', 'T', 'U', 'V','W', 'X',
              'Y', 'Z'];

Template.header.alphabets = function() {
  return Alphas;
};
```

I tested this and it works.

Basically, you can pass arrays just like cursors and each will iterate them both the same.

If you have key/value pairs in your array, you can address them just like mongo documents as well.

Answer (score 1):

Helpers usually return the whole array, not individual indexed element. Looping is done by the `{{#each}}` block. So your helper shouldn't have the parameter, and look simply like that:

```
Template.header.alphabets = function () {
    return Alphas;
};
```

And you call it directly, with no reference to `Alphas` (since your template doesn't know that variable).

```
{{#each alphabets}}
    <div class="alphabets">{{this}}</div>
{{/each}}
```

---

This is pretty natural when you think about it this way: for `#each` element of `alphabets`, print a `div` containing `this` element.

Answer (score 1):

```
Template.header.alphabets
```

depricated.

Use Template.templateName.helpers insteed.

```
<template name="newTextLabel">
  {{#each textType}}
  <span class="label label-primary pull-right">{{this}}</span>
  {{/each}}
</template>

Template.newTextLabel.helpers ({
    textType: function() {
    var xxx = ZZZ.findOne(this);
    return xxx.tag;
}
})
```

collection ZZZ has documents with array named 'tag'

Answer (score 0):

Instead iterate over an array you can use all array values as below

```js
<template name="alphabet-template">
  {{#if alphabets}}
    <div class="post-alphabet">
      <p> Element: {{alphabets}}</p>
    </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```