# meteor : How to print an array from meteors helper

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I want to generate `ul li` tag from meter helper.

Result:

```
<ul>
  <li>aaa</li>
  <li>bbb</li>
</ul>
```

my template code is

```
<template name="Mytempalte">
  <ul>
    {{#each Name}}
      ???
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

and my helper returns an array.

```
Template.Mytempalte.helpers({
  Name : function(){
    return ["aaa","bbb"];
  }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Load Array values to Template Variable in Meteor JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21775615/how-to-load-array-values-to-template-variable-in-meteor-js)

Comment: Also: [Meteor Handlebars: How to access a plain array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21234947/1439597)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `{{this}}`

instead of your `???`